# How to write an extension for graphic screens for codedui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to use codedui for winform application where some windows has graphic but I can not reach beyond graphic page by default. Codede ui recognize Control type as Client for the graphic windows.

So I want to write an extension for it , below pages describes an extension, it implements a class that derives from Control.ControlAccessibleObject, and override the AccessibilityObject property to return an object of your class. I want to ask what should I do next ? Has someone experience on this before ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/enable-coded-ui-testing-of-your-controls?view=vs-2017

```
 public partial class ChartControl : UserControl
{
 // Overridden to return the custom AccessibleObject for the control.
 protected override AccessibleObject CreateAccessibilityInstance()
 {
    return new ChartControlAccessibleObject(this);
}

// Inner class ChartControlAccessibleObject represents accessible information
// associated with the ChartControl and is used when recording tests.
public class ChartControlAccessibleObject : ControlAccessibleObject
{
    ChartControl myControl;
    public ChartControlAccessibleObject(ChartControl ctrl)
        : base(ctrl)
    {
        myControl = ctrl;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What you ask is difficult. I have tried and failed. As you say, that Microsoft page and related ones do not explain what is required. I believe that implementing the code you need requires a software developer who is an expert in Windows GUI techniques and libraries. Please also read the [help] pages for this site, asking for off-site resources is explicitly not allowed and so this question is likely to be deleted. I recommend that you delete this question.

Comment: I deleted off-site resource advice section added example code